# Docebo integration with Appery.io

Tags: api, rest, integration

I am trying to build a simple application using the appery.io online framework. I wish to use Docebo LMS REST API. How do I make authorized calls to the docebo API endpoints from within appery? Appery has support for OAuth compliant websites like Twitter and Facebook. I have no idea what authorization process does Docebo follow but I guess it is pretty close to Twitter's because like Twitter, Docebo offers two keys- API and a secret. This is the Docebo online documentation for their APIs:

https://www.docebo.com/lms-docebo-api-third-party-integration/

And here is the appery.io tutorial for building a Twitter search application :

[The appery.io twitter search app tutorial](https://devcenter.appery.io/tutorials/creating-twitter-search-app/)

So, if anyone has any idea on how to make API calls to Docebo from appery.io and perhaps elaborate upon the method, tell me about it...

Answer (score 0):

From this link: https://www.docebo.com/lms-docebo-api-third-party-integration/ -- Docebo uses Oauth2 authentication. You can use this plugin to help you with authentication: https://devcenter.appery.io/documentation/plugins/using-the-oauth-2-template-plugin/